# css ul li layout android 2.3 compatibility

Tags: android, css, layout, browser, compatibility

I made this little web gallery
http://chocochomp.com/
and I have two main problems:

- On my old Android 2.3 feature phone web browser (the one delivered with the phone), the divs are not wrapping properly.

  Actually, the different LI blocks are left floating like a stair to the right of the page without never wrapping.
- The other problem is perhaps a bit more fancybox 2 related.. so, no need to answer this part:
  On smartphones, the fancybox 2 popup gallery is not centered on the screen but on the page!

**problem:** when the page has a big height, the gallery doesn t appear on the screen..

Here is the source code: https://github.com/mime29/Choco

Thank you for you help

Comment: Maybe you should include the CSS and HTML in your code so we can see how you style the divs.

I did take a look at the website. And maybe the Android phone does not like the frame where your page is in. I'm guessing it's the same with fancybox.

Comment: AAAAA I think it s the DNS fault... The original address is: http://nameless-depths-6053.herokuapp.com/portfolios/1 and you can see all files, css, etc... At least I can on Chrome, not on my smartphone.. ;/ Thank you for your help though!

Comment: The CSS is minified ... I meant you should put the CSS and the HTML, which you think causes the problem, in your question. That way me or other people can try to solve it. 
I'm guessing you build the website with some software package? You shhould [google](http://www.google.com?q=making%20websites%20for%20mobile%20phones) for 'my website on mobile' or something. The `viewport meta-tag` is commonly used for this purpose.. 
You could also try something like [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) to design your table/grid.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I m sorry for the minified css, I ll add the sources on github. It' s a rails 3 project.